# How to create a rule to ignore all form request validation?

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I'm a beginner on Laravel. I have a form with validation, but that form can be saved as a draft. In this case, I need a way to ignore all validation rules. Someone could help me with this?

class ValidacaoProcesso extends FormRequest {

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules() {
    return [
        'NUP' => 'required:T_PROCESSO',
        'dt_recebimento' => 'required',
        'hora_recebimento' => 'required',
        'CPF' => 'required',
        'nome' => 'required',
        'sentenca_judicial' => 'required',
        'tipo_pessoa' => 'required',
        'prioridade' => 'required',
    ];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I understand your issue:

> You want to have the validation in place if the form is not being saved as a draft, however, if it is being saved as a draft, you do not want the validation in place

Here is how I propose you do it:

#### Method 1

You first of all need to have some sort of flag sent over from front end on form submission which can indicate if the form being saved should be treated as draft or not. Let us say that flag is "draft". Now based upon that flag, could add or remove the validation such as:

```
$draft = $request->input('draft');
if (!$draft) {
   //apply validation rules
}
```

#### Method 2

However sometimes it's not possible to have this "draft" flag, in those cases, you can just use the validator and if it fails then save the form as draft as one of the validation has gone wrong, instead of returning error, like so:

```
$validationArray = [
    'NUP' => 'required:T_PROCESSO',
    'dt_recebimento' => 'required',
    'hora_recebimento' => 'required',
    'CPF' => 'required',
    'nome' => 'required',
    'sentenca_judicial' => 'required',
    'tipo_pessoa' => 'required',
    'prioridade' => 'required',
];

$draft = false;
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validationArray);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $draft = true;
}
//if $draft is true then proceed with form as draft
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didn't know that I could use input request inside the Class. I solved using something like this:

Comment: @IgordaSilvaCoelho Please mark my answer accepted if it helped you resolve your issue so that we can close this thread on stackoverflow. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help. I didn't know that I could use input request inside the Class. I solved using something like this:

```
public function rules() {
    if ($this->draft == "Y") {
        return [];
    }
    return [
        'NUP' => 'required:T_PROCESSO',
        'dt_recebimento' => 'required',
        'hora_recebimento' => 'required',
        'CPF' => 'required',
        'nome' => 'required',
        'sentenca_judicial' => 'required',
        'tipo_pessoa' => 'required',
        'prioridade' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out rules array or return empty array in your `rules()` method, if you want to ignore validation. Better way maybe not using `ValidacaoProcesso` at all. Just replace it with simple `Request` object where you are using it